# Why does webpack warn not to compile untrusted code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to understand how does this work in case of javascript. Webpack basically minifies the javascript when it says compiling I suppose. So in this case, how can some untrusted javascript code can lead to execution of malicious code through webpack on the server? A kind person in the javascript IRC channel told me this could be achieved using inline loader syntax. But I still don't understand how this is possible.

For reference the warning displayed in the getting started page is this:

> Do not compile untrusted code with webpack. It could lead to execution
> of malicious code on your computer, remote servers, or in the Web
> browsers of the end users of your application.

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

---

More information:
There are 2 ways it can execute code, when being compiled (via loaders), and when being run. SSR would be the latter, if you compile code on your server the former. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline allows you to specify a loader without it being in the webpack config, and loaders can run whatever they want.

Comment: *Why does webpack warn not to compile untrusted code?* is that not obvious? If you don't trust the code then don't add it to your project, webpack or not. Much the same for you wouldn't run user-supplied code though eval() or run it on your server. i.e SSR or in a runtime-template-compiler etc

Comment: Its obvious that its a risk. But why exactly is that a risk is what I wanted to know. I hope you understand that.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it's obvious that using third party code is a risk, regardless of whether you use webpack or not. But quoted message puts it as if compilation with webpack introduces another kind of vulnerability that you wouldn't otherwise get, hence the question, I guess

Comment: I don't see anything in the message which says it adds an additional consideration. Code going through webpack has all the power to do anything it likes from exec to embedding XSS. If you dont trust the package, i.e its by some hack group known to put mining wares in its packages then you should not think webpack will to do anything to protect your computer, remote servers, or in the Web browsers of the end users of your application. Its a warning about untrusted code, nothing more nothing less. Because dont forget there are people who would blame webpack if they found some injected code.

Comment: also, the notice is directly under the conclusion of the NPM Scripts part, which to me it would be obvious why it's there on a Getting Started page.. for beginners who have never used NPM or such package management tool. Think you looking into it too much but don't take my word for it ask the developers why they added it https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script that is being webpacked (and any script it includes) can run code *when it is packed*, and this is by design.

That warning was [added](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/3852) after I sent an email into the npm security folks (request 86380) about webpack running code during the packing phase with this [POC](https://gist.github.com/allanlw/9df6a260d689500c7e25cb9a56bdd54d).

The trick is to abuse the "Magic Comments" feature documented [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments).

Just checked on current webpack 5.23.0 and this still works.

Apparently inline loaders are another abuse pathway. See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10231

Comment: Is this still an issue as of 03/2022 ? Is there a way to avoid the code being run? Even if you don't get malicious code now, you could get it in future if you update some npm package? Isn't this a huge security risk or am I missing something here?

Comment: @sander - I just tested on webpack 5.70.0 and it still works, yes.